# Reversing Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm just starting out with arrays and was wondering what I would have to add to this code to get the arrays to print out in reverse order.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program10 {

static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] myArr = {5, 3, 2, 6, 14, 8, 9, 14};
    int[] myArr2 = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    System.out.println("First array before being arranged");
    printArray(myArr);
    rearrangeArray(myArr);
    System.out.println("First array after being arranged");
    printArray(myArr);

    System.out.println("Second array before being arranged");
    printArray(myArr2);
    rearrangeArray(myArr2);
    System.out.println("Second array after being arranged");
    printArray(myArr2);                     

}

public static void printArray(int[] a){

}

public static void rearrangeArray(int[] b){

}
}
```

Comment: or even a simple decrementing for loop

Comment: This is a cleaner way of reversing over an array though `for (int i = array.length; --i >= 0;)` I don't like the hack `length - 1`

Answer (score 3):

```
public void printRev(int[] x){
   for(int i = x.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
   }
}
```

In this example all you have to do is go from back to front.

Comment: I think you mean `int i = x.length - 1`

Comment: Indeed. :) Good Catch

Answer (score 0):

1.) Print array by simple iterating over it.

2.) No need to Rearrange array, just print in reverse order.

```
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] myArr = { 5, 3, 2, 6, 14, 8, 9, 14 };
    int[] myArr2 = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    System.out.println("First array before being arranged");
    printArray(myArr);
    rearrangeArray(myArr);
    System.out.println("First array after being arranged");
    printArray(myArr);

    System.out.println("Second array before being arranged");
    printArray(myArr2);
    rearrangeArray(myArr2);
    System.out.println("Second array after being arranged");
    printArray(myArr2);

}

public static void printArray(int[] a) {
    for (int element : a) {
        System.out.print(element);
    }
}

public static void rearrangeArray(int[] b) {
    for(int i = b.length-1; i>=0; i--){
          System.out.print(b[i]);
       }
}
```

**output**

```
First array before being arranged
5326148914First array after being arranged
1498146235Second array before being arranged
678910Second array after being arranged
109876
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, here's an approach in Java 8 that uses the Stream API to do this.  If you're just going to use simple and small arrays, this is overkill, but is handy to know for something that may come up in the future.

```
int[] myArr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
Arrays.stream(myArr)
      .boxed() // required for the collect operation
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
      .descendingIterator() // is only present with a LinkedList
      .forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about converting your array into an ArrayList then pass it to `Collections.reverse(array);` to simply reverse your array.

```
Collections.reverse(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(myArr)));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void printArray(int[] a){
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
    }
}

public static void rearrangeArray(int[] b){
    int start = 0;
    int end = b.length - 1;
    while (start < end){
        b[start] = b[start] + b[end];
        b[end] = b[start] - b[end];
        b[start] = b[start] - b[end];
        start++;
        end--;
    }
}
```

I think you are getting familiar with Java! :)